# How to call a php function from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [how to call php function in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761448/how-to-call-php-function-in-js)
>   [Javascript and PHP functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions)

Hi,

I would like to invoke different php function with client window resolution.Consider
if the users browser is large enough, then I would like to show a message from php function as vertical and if the browser is less than 960px wide then and only I would like to show the message as horizontal component.Any suggestions please...
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions/221658#221658)

Comment: use AJAX, then some CSS trick to do the horizontal/vertical positioning

Answer (score 0):

This could help you.

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp