# Calling PHP Function within Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to know is it possible to call a php function within javascript, only and only when a condition is true. For example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (foo==bar)
{
phpFunction(); call the php function
}
</script>
```

Is there any means of doing this.. If so let me know. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function cannot be called in the way that you have illustrated above. However you can call a PHP script using AJAX, code is as shown below. Also you can find a simple example [here](http://tallymobile.com/test3.html). Let me know if you need further clarification

**Using Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function compute() {
    var params="session=123";
    $.post('myphpscript.php',params,function(data){ 
            alert(data);//for testing if data is being fetched
            var myObject = eval('(' + data + ')');
            document.getElementById("result").value=myObject(addend_1,addend_2);
        }); 
}
</script>
```

**Barebones Javascript Alternative**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function compute() {
        var params="session=123"
        var xmlHttp; 
        var addend_1=document.getElementById("par_1").value;
        var addend_2=document.getElementById("par_2").value;

        try 
        { 
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } 
        catch (e) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
            } 
            catch (e) 
            { 
                try 
                { 
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                } 
                catch (e) 
                { 
                    alert("No Ajax for YOU!"); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { 
                ret_value=xmlHttp.responseText;
                var myObject = eval('(' + ret_value + ')');
                document.getElementById("result").value=myObject(addend_1,addend_2);
            }
        }       
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "http://yoururl/getjs.php", true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlHttp.send(params);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I really have to recommend the jQuery library for Ajax. It just makes things ridiculously simpler and worry free.

Comment: Absolutely, however every newbie needs to start ground up, hence my use of barebones javascript

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just one more thing can any show me a simple jQuery.ajax example. I want to know its basic implementation.

Comment: As requested illustrated the same Ajax post request using jquery. Please refer to the links given by the other respondents or shout if you have any questions about this.

Comment: that's absolutely true, we have to know how all this works to debug low level errors, nevertheless, it's nice to add a jquery recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is server side and Javascript is client so not really (yes I know there is some server side JS). What you could do is use Ajax and make a call to a PHP page to get some results.

Comment: Here is an article on getting Ajax up and running using jQuery http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery

Comment: Wow I said exactly the same some minutes after you :)

Answer (score 2):

No that's not possible. PHP code runs ***before*** (server-side) javascript (client-side)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have it right.

However, there is a library, [XAJAX](http://www.xajax-project.org/), that helps simulate the act of calling a PHP function from JavaScript, using AJAX and a particularly designed PHP library.

It's a little complicated, and it would be much easier to learn to use $.get and $.post in jQuery, since they are better designed and simpler, and once you get your head around how they work, you won't feel the need to call PHP from JavaScript directly.

Answer (score 0):

PHP always runs before the page loads. JavaScript always runs after the page loads. They never run in tandem.

The closest solution is to use AJAX or a browser redirect to call another .php file from the server.