# calling a php function from Javascript same file

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling PHP Function within Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172976/calling-php-function-within-javascript)

I have a small JavaScript code in a php file. This JavaScript code runs some logic and in the end should call a php function which is defined in the same php file. How can I do this ? any guidance ?

Comment: my goal is to call a `php` function `DeleteEntity( relmod, module, x, 123 )` where `relmod` and `module` are `string` and `x` is an `array of integers` which is created in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ajax for that and call this same file. because php function will not initialize from javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think using [`PHPLIVEX`](http://www.phplivex.com/), can be useful too in this scenario.

PHPLIVEX has a little tag line -

*Call your php functions and class methods from javascript in one line*

This can be useful if you need to call php functions from javascript several times in your application.

Answer (score 0):

if an server-side code need to be executed , you need to call that via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

this is for sure not the best answer there is, but it should work: have your javascript make an ajax call, to your same page, using a POST parameter, so u know this is the call for that function ..    hope it is clear enough in large lines ..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. JavaScript is executed in a browser, PHP on server. The only way to do it is using AJAX request, e.g. with jQuery:

```
$.get('myurl.php', function(data){ ... });
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

That will return output produced by myphp.php file; if you want to run a single function from it, you'll need some logic that determines which function it should execute, e.g. URL parameter. However, I'd strongly advise against using url parameter value as direct function name.

Answer (score 0):

you should use jquery's ajax or post