# Call PHP on server via Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am attempting to make a dead simple webpage that does things when I click a button.

I am trying to use Javascript so I don't have to reload the main page or anything.

So I want a button that says "Shutdown", and I simply want to run shutDown.php that will shut down the server when I click on this.

I've been searching for an hour now and can't find a simple example. Could someone please post a very simple, example, or a link to one?

Many thanks :)

EDIT:
Okay so here's my pitiful attempt.. it doesn't work.. any tips?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Control Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
/*************************************
JQUERY EXAMPLE
*************************************/
$('#mysubmit').click(){
    var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': 'http://localhost/killIE.php',
        'dataType': 'json'
       });
    }
}
</script>

<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Click!" />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: added complete page version.:)

Comment: Also - do you already have server side script that will trigger shutdown. BEcause it's not as simple as it might look like, since PHP usually runs as nobody user, so it doesn't have permission to shut server down.

Comment: Thanks don't worry, I can figure out that stuff, I'm just clueless on this web stuff. Thanks again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep  - technology called called AJAX. 
You can either write it in raw javascript or use ready made libraries.
The most popular JS library nowadays (subjectively) is jQuery, I'll use it in my example.

NOTE: this will trigger your shutDown.php PHP script on the server without reloading the page. But - you won't be able to parse web requests obviously after you shutdown your server :)...

```
/*************************************
JQUERY EXAMPLE
*************************************/
$('#myShutdownButton').click(){
    var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'url': 'http://someServer.com/shutDown.php',
        'data': {'shutdownServer': 'yes'},//optional
        'dataType': 'json'
       });
    }
}
```

P.S. I assume that you know that you have to load jQuery library first in your html file header, something like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then put that jquery code inside of script tags:

```
<script>
...that jQuery code...
</script>
```

**UPDATED BY REQUEST - complete script version**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Control Page</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        //we need document.ready call to make sure that DOM loaded before we try to bind anything
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //Here we bind click event
            $('#mysubmit').bind('click', function(e){e.preventDefault();
                //This is what happens on click - we send AJAX request
                var jqueryXHR = $.ajax({
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': 'http://localhost/killIE.php',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                   });
                //And when AJAX requests complete(succeeded or failed) - we update text
                jqueryXHR.complete(function(){  
                    $('span#result').html('Oh no!!! the End is neearh! erver is shutting DoWn.')
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Kill da server!" style = "margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px;" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span id = "result">Not clicked yet - good!</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Could you please look at my edit to see what I am doing wrong still?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via javascript you should do an Ajax call, I would recommend you to use [jQuery](http://php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/) for it, but it can be done only with [javascript](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) if you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open the php file in a popup? I suppose if you really want to get fancy you can load it into a modal popup. I take it whatever "shutDown.php" is that it just runs on page load. So it probably doesn't matter too much how you call it.

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function open_win()
 {
 window.open("http://www.url.com/shutDown.php")
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<input type=button value="Shut Down" onclick="open_win()" />

</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick tutorial that can teach you how to do this: http://aleembawany.com/2005/09/01/ajax-instant-tutorial

Though, I have to say that it's not very safe to have a public php file that has the power to shut down your server. If the wrong people got a hold of the url...

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is called AJAX. Search it up!

Answer (score -1):

do one thing.. That when you click on to the shutdownm button just open this page on next page dont open in same page and execute it.. And close the new page after some period..
So u dont need to reload the page..
Hope this work.. Try this..