# Call php function from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Is there a way I can run a php function through a JS function?

something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
document.getElementById("php_code").innerHTML="<?php 
query("hello");       ?>";    
}
</script>

<a href="#" style="display:block; color:#000033; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px;"     
onclick="test(); return false;"> test </a>
<span id="php_code"> </span>
```

I basically want to run the php function `query("hello")`, when I click on the href called "Test" which would call the php function.

Comment: simply no, there is no way to do this, except calling the required method using ajax.

Comment: You know: PHP runs on the server, but JS on the client? This _cannot_ work this way.

Comment: wait wait, isn't `<?php query("hello"); ?>` rendered by php when page is loaded? if yes then he can get output of `query("hello")` in js function.

Comment: I know the code above is wrong, but I just used it to show what I want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions)

Comment: I have found this: http://myitviewoflife.blogspot.com/2010/06/japi-direct-direct-call-php-methods.html but I dont really know how to use it

Comment: @brian-driscoll I don't believe this question is an EXACT duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856961/how-to-call-a-php-class-method-from-a-javascript-function, because the original question is about using a **php class method within javascript** and this question is about **general php scripting within javascript**. The _CLOSED_ question is much more involved as it requires passing a PHP object to javascript while maintaining its methods. I strongly feel that the _CLOSED_ question should be re-opened and addressed as I am now also searching for a solution.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

This is, in essence, what [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax) is **for**. Your page loads, and you add an event to an element. When the user causes the event to be triggered, say by clicking something, your Javascript uses the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) to send a request to a server.

After the server responds (presumably with output), another Javascript function/event gives you a place to work with that output, including simply sticking it into the page like any other piece of HTML.

You can do it "by hand" with plain Javascript , or you can use jQuery. Depending on the size of your project and particular situation, it may be more simple to just use plain Javascript .

## Plain Javascript

In this very basic example, we send a request to `myAjax.php` when the user clicks a link. The server will generate some content, in this case "hello world!". We will put into the HTML element with the id `output`.

**The javascript**

```
// handles the click event for link 1, sends the query
function getOutput() {
  getRequest(
      'myAjax.php', // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}  
// handles drawing an error message
function drawError() {
    var container = document.getElementById('output');
    container.innerHTML = 'Bummer: there was an error!';
}
// handles the response, adds the html
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    var container = document.getElementById('output');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
}
// helper function for cross-browser request object
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
    var req = false;
    try{
        // most browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // IE
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            // try an older version
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
    if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4) {
            return req.status === 200 ? 
                success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="return getOutput();"> test </a>
<div id="output">waiting for action</div>
```

**The PHP**

```
// file myAjax.php
<?php
  echo 'hello world!';
?>
```

**Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/m8CTk/**

---

## With a javascript library (jQuery et al)

Arguably, that is a lot of Javascript code. You can shorten that up by tightening the blocks or using more terse logic operators, of course, but there's still a lot going on there. If you plan on doing a lot of this type of thing on your project, you might be better off with a javascript library.

Using the same HTML and PHP from above, this is your entire script (with jQuery included on the page). I've tightened up the code a little to be more consistent with jQuery's general style, but you get the idea:

```
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getOutput() {
   $.ajax({
      url:'myAjax.php',
      complete: function (response) {
          $('#output').html(response.responseText);
      },
      error: function () {
          $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

**Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/WQXXT/**

Don't rush out for jQuery just yet: adding any library is still adding hundreds or thousands of lines of code to your project just as surely as if you had written them. Inside the jQuery library file, you'll find similar code to that in the first example, plus a **whole lot more**. That may be a good thing, it may not. Plan, and consider your project's current size and future possibility for expansion and the target environment or platform.

If this is all you need to do, write the plain javascript once and you're done.

**Documentation**

- *AJAX* on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax
- `XMLHttpRequest` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest
- `XMLHttpRequest` on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- jQuery - http://jquery.com/download/
- `jQuery.ajax` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: -1, half an answer, OP asked how to call a php function from javascript. Pou only showed how to call a php PAGE. You need to add post variables in the ajax call and php checking for those post variables and then calling that php function if those post variables exist.

Comment: @Hanoncs With nearly infinite possible arrangements of server-side code, it is not constructive or even possible for me to guess what architecture the OP is using. It is not germane to the immediate problem statement, either, since the OP does not reference POST (or GET) or the need to pass values. I think your downvote is misplaced, and I'll not be adding to my answer arbitrary speculation about a subject not contained in the OP. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: When I use your code, I get an error because of the use of "var" in front of the function declaration. Removing "var" and it works.

Answer (score 17):

PHP is evaluated at the server; javascript is evaluated at the client/browser, thus you can't call a PHP function from javascript *directly*. But you can issue an HTTP request to the server that will activate a PHP function, with AJAX.

Comment: @Hanoncs: This **is** the answer. OP asked whether you can execute a PHP function via JS. The answer is - **you can't**. If he would have asked whether you can issue an HTTP request that will make the web server to activate a PHP script which will run a PHP function - then yes - **that** is possible. But he didn't ask for this, ergo I don't write irrelevant data.

Comment: Haha come on man, you know that's what the OP meant by his question. if he knew how to explain it exactly like that he would already know how to do it.

Answer (score 11):

The only way to execute PHP from JS is AJAX.
You can send data to server (for eg, GET /ajax.php?do=someFunction)
then in ajax.php you write:

```
function someFunction() {
    echo 'Answer';
}

if ($_GET['do'] === "someFunction") {
    someFunction();
}
```

and then, catch the answer with JS (i'm using jQuery for making AJAX requests)

Probably you'll need some format of answer. See JSON or XML, but JSON is easy to use with JavaScript. In PHP you can use function json_encode($array); which gets array as argument.

Answer (score 5):

I recently published a jQuery plugin which allows you to make PHP function calls in various ways: https://github.com/Xaxis/jquery.php

Simple example usage:

```
// Both .end() and .data() return data to variables
var strLenA = P.strlen('some string').end();
var strLenB = P.strlen('another string').end();
var totalStrLen = strLenA + strLenB;
console.log( totalStrLen ); // 25

// .data Returns data in an array
var data1 = P.crypt("Some Crypt String").data();
console.log( data1 ); // ["$1$Tk1b01rk$shTKSqDslatUSRV3WdlnI/"]
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious bias people have in regard to calling PHP functions via JavaScript, explain to me exactly why my answer has been down voted as much as it has? I'm legitimately answering the question at hand with a solution, am I not?

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to make a Javascript call to a PHP function written on the page (client-side script). The PHP part 'to be executed' only occurs on the server-side on load or refreshing'. You avoid 'some' server-side resources. So, manipulating the DOM:

```
<?PHP

echo "You have executed the PHP function 'after loading o refreshing the page<br>";
echo "<i><br>The server programmatically, after accessing the command line resources on the server-side, copied the 'Old Content' from the 'text.txt' file and then changed 'Old Content' to 'New Content'. Finally sent the data to the browser.<br><br>But If you execute the PHP function n times your page always displays 'Old Content' n times, even though the file content is always 'New Content', which is demonstrated (proof 1) by running the 'cat texto.txt' command in your shell. Displaying this text on the client side proves (proof 2) that the browser executed the PHP function 'overflying' the PHP server-side instructions, and this is because the browser engine has restricted, unobtrusively, the execution of scripts on the client-side command line.<br><br>So, the server responds only by loading or refreshing the page, and after an Ajax call function or a PHP call via an HTML form. The rest happens on the client-side, presumably through some form of 'RAM-caching</i>'.<br><br>";

function myPhp(){
echo"The page says: Hello world!<br>";

echo "The page says that the Server '<b>said</b>': <br>1. ";
echo exec('echo $(cat texto.txt);echo "Hello world! (New content)" > texto.txt');echo "<br>";
echo "2. I have changed 'Old content' to '";
echo exec('echo $(cat texto.txt)');echo ".<br><br>";
echo "Proofs 1 and 2 say that if you want to make a new request to the server, you can do: 1. reload the page, 2. refresh the page, 3. make a call through an HTML form and PHP code, or 4. do a call through Ajax.<br><br>";
}
?>

<div id="mainx"></div>

<script>
function callPhp(){
var tagDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
tagDiv1.id = 'contentx';
tagDiv1.innerHTML = "<?php myPhp(); ?>";
document.getElementById("mainx").appendChild(tagDiv1);
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="CallPHP" onclick="callPhp()">
```

Note: The texto.txt file has the content 'Hello world! (Old content).

The 'fact' is that whenever I click the 'CallPhp' button I get the message 'Hello world!' printed on my page. Therefore, a server-side script is not always required to execute a PHP function via Javascript.

But the execution of the bash commands only happens while the page is loading or refreshing, never because of that kind of Javascript apparent-call raised before. Once the page is loaded, the execution of bash scripts requires a true-call (PHP, Ajax) to a server-side PHP resource.

So, If you don't want the user to know what commands are running on the server:

- You 'should' use the execution of the commands indirectly through a PHP script on the server-side (PHP-form, or Ajax on the client-side).

Otherwise:

- If the output of commands on the server-side is not delayed:

  - You 'can' use the execution of the commands directly from the page (less 'cognitive' resources—less PHP and more Bash—and less code, less time, usually easier, and more comfortable if you know the bash language).
- Otherwise:

  - You 'must' use Ajax.

Comment: This doesn't make a call to a PHP function, but shows the value of the result when the page is loaded. But indeed, could work with some cases although a bit trivial.

Comment: The function fires after the page loads or refreshes and occurs as many times as you click the button (proofs 1 and 2). But it's not a true 'server' call (bash code is not executed), it's just a call to a PHP function executable by the browser engine (it uses a kind of RAM-cache).

Comment: It's not trivial in localhost server applications, eg trafex/php-nginx (Docker). Because the knowledge and use of bash code is very useful at the command line level on the desktop. There it can be combined with python, Perl, etc.