# Call a php function (not on a file) from a href

Tags: php, function, href

Is there a way to make this `<a>` element do a php function or action when clicked, so when the item is clicked, instead of navigating to a php page, simply call the function and execute it, so when you click on it it does this(for example) `echo 'FOO';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clicking is only done on the client-side. So javascript is the best tool to execute the function.

You could do something like:

```
<a onclick="alert('foo');" ...
```

If you must have server content as a result of the click, then you'll want to have javascript issue an AJAX call to get the content and then display it. Check into the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. It handles those types of things very, very well.

Comment: Using ajax, <a> can make a server request and handle the response.

Comment: Aah, the ever evolving answer, I revoke my downvote. (Yes, it was the reason)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if he was just wanting to display something, or get something from the server.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is to use AJAX, see http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

It is technically true that this can only be done on the client-side through something like javascript. But with javascript you can use AJAX to call a PHP page that does something like `echo FOO';`