# How to use my PHP function in JavaScript code

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to use my PHP function in JavaScript like this:

PHP code:

```
function checkevents($date){
    $ev = new CalendarModelEventss();
    $wh = "`event_date` = '".$date."'";
    $all = $ev->getAllEvents('event_date', $wh);
    if($all == $date){
        //echo 'event is available'.$all;   
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        //echo 'event is NOT available' .'--'. $all;
    }
}
```

and JavaScript code:

```
var yyyy = date.getLocalFullYear(true, this.dateType);
var mm = date.getLocalMonth(true,this.dateType);
var dd = iday;
var ddddd = yyyy+'/'+mm+'/'+dd;

if(<?php checkevents( ?>ddddd<?php ) ?>){
     cell.className += " eventsss ";
}
```

but it doesn't work, and I have PHP error (`syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in ...`).

Comment: That's not possible - PHP cannot be executed client-side.

Comment: Basically understanding technologies you are trying to use helps. So maybe checking what "server side" and "client side" terms mean, would solve your doubts too?

Comment: If you;re so particular about using php for the validation, you need to send the data to server and validate using AJAX.

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript might help you.

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript might help you.

Answer (score 3):

As the previous speaker said, it's impossible to directly call php functions from javascript. PHP could be used to output javascript though.

In your case you would need to send an ajax-request from the client side (with javascript) that executes the php code (on the server side), fetches the output and puts it into your if-statement.

If you do not know alot about javascript/AJAX you could take a look at jQuery or another similar framework.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is parsed on client side and PHP on Server side.
Without `AJAX` this is impossible.

Example with JQuery:

PHP:

```
...
    echo "true";//or something else that indicates the success
} else {
    echo "false";//or something else that indicates the failure
}
...
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "URL TO YOU PHP SCRIPT",
  cache: false
}).done(function( html ) {
  if(html.match(/true/g)){
     cell.className += " eventsss ";
  }
});
```

Comment: More like: without sending a request to the server it would be impossible. You could use techniques like JSONP or even websocket to trigger a server-side php.

Comment: Thank you, but i wanna use in for statement, Is not a problem to use ajax?

Comment: you can use .match(/true/g) as I wrote above. It looks for the "true" word in the response and returns true or false so you can work with it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call php function using javascript directly as both of them are on different sides.So what you do is make an AJAX call with certain parameters and after that call that php function directly from that php file with the parameters to be validated.

And Send back the output back to javascript by echoing the output and do whatever with it on javascript.