# PHP button action not working

Tags: php

The action i implemented on a submit button in PHP isn'n executed. Everything works fine, no error but when i click the button nothing happens. Notepad++ sees that the file `lines.php` has been modified.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Watch your Language
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <H2 align="center">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" onclick="English()" name="introdu" value="Choose english">
        </form>
        <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="bot.php">Talk to robot</a>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function English()
{<?php
         $myFile = "lines.php";
         $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');

$eng = <<<TEST
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public $mp3data;
    function __construct($text="") {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $lang_en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=\{$text}";
            $lang_ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q=\{$text}";
            $lang_fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=\{$text}";
            $language=$lang_en;
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents($language);
        }
    }

    function setText($text) {
        $text = trim($text);
        if(!empty($text)) {
            $text = urlencode($text);
            $en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=\{$text}";
            $ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q=\{$text}";
            $fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q=\{$text}";
            $lang=$en;
            $this->mp3data = file_get_contents($lang);
            return  $this->mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile($filename) {
        $filename = trim($filename);
        if(!empty($filename)) {
            return file_put_contents($filename,$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
TEST;
echo $eng;
fwrite($fh, $eng);
fclose($fh); 
?>
alert("File created");
}
</script>
```

Comment: PHP is executed on server side

Comment: I'm running it on localhost using wamp

Comment: you cannot run php with a javascript event, unless you use ajax

Comment: can you help me implement ajax method to this code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially only available via an Ajax call. Here is a good example that I found on Stack Overflow already:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7165616/1439793

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the same method and it works perfectly

```
<html>
<head><title>Umanizator</title>

</head>
<body><H2 align="center">
<form method="post">
Intrebare
 <input type="text" name="intrebare">
Raspuns
 <input type="text" name="raspuns">
<input type="submit" onclick="Confirmare()" name="introdu" value="Exporta">
</form>
<a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="bot.php">Discuta cu robotul</a></h2>
</body>
</html>

<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("robo") or die(mysql_error());

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$intrebare=$_POST['intrebare'];
$raspuns=$_POST['raspuns'];
$cod1='mysql_query("INSERT INTO dialog  (intrebare, raspuns) VALUES (\'';
$cod2="'  ,  '";
$cod3="') \")  or die(mysql_error());";


$myFile = "lines.txt";
$intrebari = "intrebari.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$op = fopen($intrebari, 'a') or die("can't open file");

$delimiteaza="\n /*---*/  \n";

fwrite($fh, $delimiteaza);
fwrite($fh, $cod1);
fwrite($fh, $intrebare);
fwrite($fh, $cod2);
fwrite($fh, $raspuns);
fwrite($fh, $cod3);
fwrite($op, $intrebare);
fwrite($op, $delimiteaza);

fclose($fh);


?>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function Confirmare()
{
<?php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO dialog  (intrebare, raspuns) VALUES ('".$intrebare."'  ,  '".$raspuns."') ")  or die(mysql_error());
?>
alert("Linia de cod a fost exportata!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: php is run at page loading so yes your INSERT will work but not when you click on the button, you could try loading the page and check your database before clicking

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have rewrited the $eng file using the following:

```
<<<TEST
<?php
class TextToSpeech {
    public \$mp3data;
    function __construct(\$text="") {
        \$text = trim(\$text);
        if(!empty(\$text)) {
           \$text = urlencode(\$text);
            \$lang_en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={\$text}";
            \$lang_ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q={\$text}";
            \$lang_fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q={\$text}";
            \$language=\$lang_en;
            \$this->mp3data = file_get_contents(\$language);
        }
    }

    function setText(\$text) {
        \$text = trim(\$text);
        if(!empty(\$text)) {
            \$text = urlencode(\$text);
            \$en="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q={\$text}";
            \$ro="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ro&q={\$text}";
            \$fr="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=fr&q={\$text}";
            \$lang=\$en;
            \$this->mp3data = file_get_contents(\$lang);
            return  \$this->mp3data;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function saveToFile(\$filename) {
        \$filename = trim(\$filename);
        if(!empty(\$filename)) {
            return file_put_contents(\$filename,\$this->mp3data);
        } else { return false; }
    }
}
?>
TEST;
```