# Call php inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, stored-procedures

Hi friends I have a PHP file as Shown below and I need to call a stored procedure inside javascript ie When i confirm yes I need to call the stored procedure . How should I include the following php code in IF loop of js(ie when i confirm yes)

This is the stored procedure:

```
 $sql = "CALL procedure(?);";
 $parameters = array($buyer_user_id);
 $query = $this->db->query($sql, $parameters);
```

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
echo "<script>if (confirm('are u sure ?')) {";
echo "}";
echo " else {";
echo "}</script>";
?>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX to 'talk' with the php code.

Comment: PHP works on server side and javascrpt works on client side

Comment: Use the ajax to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
         var request = window.XMLHttpRequest() ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

         request.open("POST", "phpfile.php", true);
         request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         request.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (request.readyState == 4 && (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0 /*Fixes a FF bug*/)) {
                 alert(request.responseText); // should return "example1-example2"
             }
         }
         request.send("data1=example1&data2=example2"); // you can send data here
    }
</script>
```

phpfile.php:

```
<?php
     return $_POST['data1'] . "-" . $_POST['data2'];
?>
```

I really dislike how complicated traditional AJAX is compared to using a library, but hope this gave you the idea.