# how to call php function from javascript "duplicate"

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have a `.php` file which has so far two functions. Here is the file :

```
          <?php
        function Register()
        {
        $Name=$_POST["NameTxt"];
        $Email=$_POST["EmailTxt"] ;
        $Pass=$_POST["PasswordTxt"];
        $RePass = $_POST["RePasswordTxt"];
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\- ]*$/",$Name) or empty($Name)) {
          header("Location: http://localhost/tutorial/Mdaeg-login.html");
        }
        elseif (!filter_var($Email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)or empty($Email) or empty($Pass)) {
              header("Location: http://localhost/tutorial/Mdaeg-login.html");
        }
        elseif($Pass!=$RePass)
        {
              header("Location: http://localhost/tutorial/Mdaeg-login.html");   
        }

        $connect=mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "Password") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("Database", $connect);
        $read="select  Email from users where Email='$Email'";
        $result=mysql_query($read,$connect);
        $rowcount=mysql_num_rows($result); 
        if($rowcount==0)
        {
        $sql="INSERT INTO Users (Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('$Name','$Email','$Pass')";
        mysql_query($sql,$connect);
        }
        mysql_close($connect);

        header("Location: http://localhost/tutorial/Mdaeg-login.html");
        }
    function Login()
    {
$Email=$_POST["EmailLogin"] ;
$Pass=$_POST["PassLogin"];
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "kamal3007") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Mdaeg", $connect);
$read="select  Email,Password from users where Email='$Email'";
$result=mysql_query($read,$connect);
$rowcount=mysql_num_rows($result); 
mysql_close($connect);
if($rowcount==1)
{
      header("Location: http://localhost/tutorial/Profile.html");

}

    }

        ?>
```

I have two questions about this code. First,is there any possible way to call a .php function from javascript? Second question, in the second function I'll get the email and the password from the database, but how can I read each column separately so that I can check the password?
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: 1) Directly not possible. You need to make a request to the php script. For example with AJAX.

Comment: hmm, okay @CharlotteDunois, can you give me an example or a link about it ?

Comment: 2) You need to fetch the rows. E.g. with mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: possible duplicate, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript

Comment: Also you are still using the deprecated mysql_* functions. I recommend to migrate to PDO.

Comment: @biancamihai, okay dude, sorry my bad :)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois, I very new to php, thank you so much for your help <3

Comment: @PaulCrovella, thank you dude, but this is no my problem, okay maybe I should says: is there any possible way to call a php function from javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to post data from your page using ajax function

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

And then create a class file having those two functions

```
class clsname{
  public function Register(){}
  public function Login(){}
}

try {
  //  catch the post veriable
  // create an object to call function/method of class
  // get return value like header location and redirect
}catch(Exception $e){
}
```

And you can you the mysql_fetch_array to fetch the value, but those are deprecated function try to use php PDO native library, that will definately help you as per future prespactive

Answer (score 2):

You have to call a ajax function

```
var function getOutput() {
 $.ajax({
  url:'your_function_url',
  complete: function (response) {
      $('#output').html(response.responseText);
  },
  error: function () {
      $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
  }
 });
return false;
}
```