# php fwrite function onclick

Tags: php, function, onclick, fwrite

i want to make a clickable element. every time the user is clicking on that element the server is running the following php function without reloading the page with a $_GET value:

```
function addOne() {
$num = file_get_contents("number.txt");
$fp = fopen('number.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $num + 1);
fclose($fp);
echo "<script>document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = " . $num ."</script>";
}
```

Comment: Use an AJAX call to the PHP script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Comment: please give me the code. i know i can use AJAX i just dont know how can i use it to call a PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

If you create file called `addOne.php` which calls the `addOne` function and give your button an id of `add-one`, then you can use jQuery to post to it on every click.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add-one).on('click', function() {
    $.post('/addOne.php');
  });
});
</script>
```