# How to dynamically disable day in responsive calendar (w3 widgets)?

Tags: javascript, php

Situation: Some companies' weekends are Saturdays and Sundays or Fridays and Saturdays. So the calendar should be able to disable those day dynamically as following.

[image]

[image]

I have some basic idea of how to do it with javascript:

```
// determine weekends
    if(dayType === 'fri' || dayType === 'sat') {
          day.append($("<a class='disabled'>" + dayNum + "</a>").attr("data-day", dayNum).attr("data-month", monthNum).attr("data-year", yearNum));
      }else {
          day.append($("<a>" + dayNum + "</a>").attr("data-day", dayNum).attr("data-month", monthNum).attr("data-year", yearNum));
      }
```

How to make it dynamic and based on companies' weekends after getting data from database using php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your javaScript does it, all you have to do is retrieve the information from the database and call a function that disable the days, the query to the database will depend on how it's designed, but you could create a table weekendDays and use the company name as search key (better an id), that way you could do a select days from weekenDays where name='Canonical'; days could be a string with comma separators... days = {"fri,sat"}, then you split the result and call disableDays sending the split text as parameter.

```
function disableDays(dayToDisable){
         // determine weekends
     for(idx=0; idx<dayToDisable.length; idx++){
       if(dayType === dayToDisable[idx]) {
           day.append($("<a class='disabled'>" + dayNum + "</a>").attr("data-day", dayNum).attr("data-month", monthNum).attr("data-year", yearNum));
       }
       else {
             day.append($("<a>" + dayNum + "</a>").attr("data-day", dayNum).attr("data-month", monthNum).attr("data-year", yearNum));
       }
   }
}
```

You have to call the function with each result the query to the database returns (the weekends)

well something like that, please check the code I write it as an example and didn't test it, there could be better ways to do it :)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I totally get the idea of how to do it. But the code above is written in js file. Is there a way i can get the data from a php file and use them in the js file?

Comment: ok then you need to use AJAX like is splained here: [link AJAX - Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Comment: you must call your php like this:

`$.ajax({
      url:'yourPHPscript.php',
      complete: function (response) {
          disableDays(response.split(","));
      },
      error: function () {
          alert("Error!");
      }
  });
}`

Comment: @DIEGO CARRASCAL I see your excelent response. It help me too much. Please, I need also know the month and year when the user click on next /prev link or  into event onMonthChange. The values data['year] and data['month'] don´t work there. Somehelp will be appreciate.

Comment: I suggest you to create a new question with your code, because the answer I give to this question was based on my analysis of the code and not in previous experience with it... Sorry I can't help more, but if you do create a question with your code I'll try to help you :)

Answer (score -1):

I figured something out: using CSS. Every 'div' for the days has got classes (wed past or sun future). So we have to just specify CSS for them. It's not related to OP but it's just for record.