# Invoke JavaScript function using "onclick" in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

On clicking the text, JS function should get executed.
In **HTML**:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="clickthis();">Table 1</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In **PHP**:

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';

function clickthis(){
$search_table = "SELECT `table1` FROM `booktable` WHERE `table1`='booked';"
$query = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$search_table);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){
  "INSERT INTO `booktable` (table1`) VALUES(`booked`)";
  echo'Table booked successfully.';
?>
```

Have I placed the `onclick` function correctly in `HTML`? 
Whenever I click on the text `Table 1`, `clickthis()` function should get executed but how can I achieve the result using `PHP, JavaScript & HTML`.
**P.S.** *I don't want to use button click & `dbconnect.php` is external php file.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the PHP script through an AJAX call. The way you are approaching the structure is wrong.

You can take the following steps.

1. Create a PHP script and serve it on say `/booktable`
2. Have a `js` script to fetch a the above url through an AJAX call.
3. Bind js function to onClick in your HTML markup.

Comment: Can you plz give an example showing the right approach?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript