# Is it possible to call PHP functions from within ReactJS

Tags: php, reactjs, interaction

We have a website front end that is written in ReactJS and the backend is being developed in PHP.

Is it possible to call these functions from within ReactJS?

Comment: js runs on the client, php runs on the server. neither can call a function in the other.

Comment: Would we need to implement an interface between them such as RESTful?

Comment: Make an AJAX call to a page that execute the php function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly call a PHP method from ReactJS as PHP is a server-side language and ReactJS is a Javascript framework which means it's client-side language.

What you need to do is to send an AJAX request using ReactJS to your server and use the response.

Take a look at this link: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

The link describes how to load initial data from server using AJAX.