# Sending PHP variables to JavaScript through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm writing a program that will generate random numbers on both JavaScript and PHP pages and display them on the JavaScript/Html page.

So far I have both pages successfully generating the numbers, but I don't know how to reach out from the JavaScript page to the external PHP page to retrieve the number and store it into a JS variable.

Here's what I have so far.

JavaScript:

```
function roll()
    {
        var rollOne; //= Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        var rollTwo;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.open("GET", "filename.php", true);
        request.send();                 
    }
```

I know the JS random is commented out, that's not important right now.

PHP:

```
<?php
    sleep(5);
    $random =(rand(1,6));
    echo $random;
?>
```

So how do I take $random from the php document, send it over to the JavaScript page, and store it into a variable to access later?

I'm sure a similar question has been asked thousands of times before on this site, but from what I have searched I haven't found anything that made sense to me.

Comment: Please study some ajax tutorials ... they are easy to find all over the web

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mozilla docs on AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started#Step_2_%E2%80%93_Handling_the_server_response) explain it well.  Before calling `.open` and `.send`, set up a function for `XMLHttpRequest` to run when the response comes back from the server:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    // The request is complete
    if (request.status === 200) {
      // Server responded with HTTP status code 200 (OK)
      // Here's your server's random value
      random = request.responseText;
    } else {
      alert('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the responseText value of the returned data. In other words, the data that you echo from php can be accessed in your javascript using responseText and stored in a variable.