# JavaScript Library with Bluebeam

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, form-fields

I'm looking for some information/references/examples and how to use javascript in Bluebeam.

Bluebeam said that you can refer to the following AcroForm documentation :

- https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_developer_guide.pdf
- https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

But while trying to use some objects / properties / methods of those references, it seems than only some of them can be used. So, as there is no dedicated Bluebeam references, it's really tedious to figure out what can be done in JS within Bluebeam.

I've looked at all the examples from Bluebeam as this one :
https://support.bluebeam.com/articles/how-can-i-create-interactive-stamps/

But this is very basic. Even while looking in details there is no much information.

Here is for example something that I'm trying to do :
- Open a dialog just before saving with the "Doc/WillSave" event
- Fill the different fields of the dialog
- Use the fields content to save file or pre-fill the save field from the saveAs dialog
- Save the file.

Obviously, the js-file is in a folder with security rights. But most of those functions seems not to exist in Bluebeam.

I've contacted the BB support but with not any feedback yet.
Also, I found out other related post (@Logan) but there is not much follow-up about how it was solved (or not) => [How to Save a .pdf document using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683485/how-to-save-a-pdf-document-using-javascript/42691796#42691796?newreg=be99f80a08ad4abba38724cdf05a2a9c)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The javascript engine closely resembles that of acrobat, but there are some differences. Bluebeam desperately needs to release their own API reference.

That being said, I do have an unofficial Bluebeam API reference file that was given to me during the conference last year. Unfortunately I can't attach excel files to these posts, but I produced a .jpeg image where I have compiled all of the data for you:

[image: Bluebeam API description]

I have found some success in using this as a guide to first check to see what operations are available in Bluebeam, and then using the Acrobat API reference to find the syntax.

I hope this is helpful. Please post if you come across a better reference guide for the Bluebeam-specific API.

I have not had much success with requesting reference guides from the Bluebeam team, I think they try to refrain from distributing javascript references since their "eXtreme" software package has limited pre-built javascript code as a selling point. Maybe with some increased pressure they will realize the need to release a comprehensive guide for their API.

Best of luck! Again, the Bluebeam API file is below:
[Bluebeam API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEdU1.jpg)

Comment: Thank you Logan. This a good start. However I don’t see any Save Method... Would you mind to share your script for files saving or to give me some tips ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm adding that I cannot find Javascript scripting anymore in Bluebeam Revu basic version. I think they have removed it in about 2020, and it seems to be now [limited to the eXtreme version](https://support.bluebeam.com/online-help/revu20/Content/RevuHelp/Menus/Tools/Form/JavaScript/JavaScript.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Bluebeam Revu 2019 includes two reference documents in their Help folder:
C:\Program Files\Bluebeam Software\Bluebeam Revu\2019\Help

- Bluebeam Revu eXtreme Script Reference.pdf

  - Applies to Bluebeam Revu eXtreme
  - Version 1.0.8, published February 27, 2019
- Bluebeam Script Reference.pdf

  - Applies to Bluebeam Q and Bluebeam Revu eXtreme
  - Version 2.0.10, published February 27, 2019