# PHP Elements add EventListener

Tags: javascript, php, html, backend, event-listener

I'm currently working on a website which allows the costumer to personally add movies to a database. So I wrote a PHP class which initially loads all the data needed from a database and creating a table which kind of looks like this:

[image: My Question now:]

How do I *theoretically* proceed to make those buttons work(Which, as they change things in a database should "execute" php-functions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*theoretically* this is how you should proceed:

## First the database piece

1. you will create 4 fields

   - each field corresponding to the table header (notice there should be no space in the name of the field) -- movie_id will be numerical, name will be varchar, etc.

## Next the code

- I take it the second row are all  inside  tag? if not make it so
- Make sure the form method is POST
- I recommend making the action of the form go to another page (keeps it clean)

*user clicks on "save changes" button*

- On the other page (specified in form action), you will receive the data in your $_POST var; based on each input's name, this will be accessible in post. So for example, if your input name for "name" field is "movie_name" then this data will be in: $_POST['movie_name']
- Store each field's POST data in a variable... i.e. $movieName = $_POST['movie_name'] ---- **THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE! YOU SHOULD NEVER ACCESS POST DATA DIRECTLY!! YOU MUST SANITIZE/VALIDATE ETC. THIS DATA BEFORE STORING IN DATABASE**
- Assuming you have a database link already established, simply insert the data into the table you created earlier

Hope this helps you get started!

Best,

-Rush

Comment: my pleasure; just post to this thread if you get stuck at any point... some steps above were left intentionally vague for you to explore.