# How to use j query element on {{ Laravel Blade }}

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, laravel-blade

**I need to use this element val to select a row from database using Laravel Blade like the attachment img pls

[image]

Comment: Share your error and code in text format

Comment: Your logic is circular. The value of the `#frm` element is based on a query which is based on the value of the `#frm` element (ignoring the fact that this wouldn't work anyway because you're mixing client-side and server-side code).

Comment: Please don't upload pictures of code on StackOverflow.

Comment: Also, see [this question on calling Php from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7165395/1218980).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you will need to use ajax requests to do this.

Please read [this article on the differences between client and server side programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171210/153671).