# Use php function inside script tag

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have this on.Click script which should trigger a PHP function after it's clicked:

```
<script>
$( "#test" ).on( "click", function() 
{
$assignClick(1);
});
</script>
```

This is the #test div where when user clicks the text "click me" it process everything:

```
<div id="test">
Click here
</div>
```

This is the assignClick function:

```
<?
function assignClick($id)
{
$db->Query("UPDATE `something` SET `something` = `something` +1 WHERE `something` = '".$id."'");
}
?>
```

$id stays for userid.

But doesnt work as value doesn't get updated on database. Maybe I'am doing something wrong?

Tried to transform assignClick from PHP to script but nothing.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP are two different languages - PHP is executed on the server, before any HTML or JavaScript is processed by the browser.   After the PHP has finished and the result is sent to the browser, then the JavaScript is executed by the browser.  Therefore a PHP function is not available in JavaScript.

Comment: So what I can do?

Comment: See the answers to this question for options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript

Comment: Use AJAX, https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/...or some other newer technology that can make requests to back end. Also parameterize queries and use prepared statements.