# Call PHP Function by Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm new for Web sites.I have a text box in my page and what i need is when onBlur that text box, call a php method that include sql query.I found something like on the web, but still does net work it.Am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Greet']))
   {
      echo $_POST['Greet'];
  }
?>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function sayHi()
{
     var value = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         url: "page.php",
        data: "Greet="+$("#Greeting").val(),
        async: false
        }).responseText;
}

</script>

<input type="text" name="Greeting" id="Greeting" onblur="sayHi()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call php function from javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

Comment: value variable contains your response use it.

Comment: `alert(value);` in your function `sayHi` and see what's inside.

Comment: when I     alert(value); it shows all the page code in an alert box..:(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript and PHP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221396/javascript-and-php-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exit your php for usage in same script, ajax will return entire html.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Greet']))
    {
        echo $_POST['Greet'];
        die;
    }
?>
```

`value` will have your response `alert(value)`

later edit:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Greet']))
    {
        echo $_POST['Greet'];
        die;
    }
?><html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sayHi()
{
    var value = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: "Greet="+$("#Greeting").val(),
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    $('#result').html(value);
}

</script>
<span id="result"></span>
<input type="text" name="Greeting" id="Greeting" onblur="sayHi()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for quick response dude, but isset($_POST['Greet']) will not true here..:(

Comment: did you add the jQuery library?

Comment: yes! this is it right?
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks buddy.. the text what i type on the text box should be echo in the page..is that the result?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the jQuery script to your page to make $.ajax work.

Like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/1600892/older ! I missed it, but problem still the same,:isset($_POST['Greet']) is false.